# Bazaar shared repository structure with/without working tree

Tags: bazaar

I'm using bazaar with the following shared repository structure on network drive:

```
proj_name (shared repo **with working tree**)  

.bzr  
developer a (integrator) (FOLDER)
    trunk      (branch)
    feature a  (branch)
    feature b  (branch)
developer b (FOLDER)
    trunk      (branch)
    feature a  (branch)
    feature b  (branch)
developer c  (FOLDER)
    trunk      (branch)
    feature a  (branch)
    feature b  (branch)
formal version (branch)
```

I want that formal version branch will be branch **without** working tree, where all the other branches will be **with**  working tree.
Is that possible?

NOTE : I tried to create the formal version branch with `bzr push N:\Projects\proj1\formal --no-tree` but its still create the working tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two solutions for this probelm:

In case of existing branch with tree you need to use `'bzr remove-tree PATH` (Solution from Martin Pool)

In case you want to **create** branch without tree , the `bzr branch --no-tree` is what you need (Solution from jelmer)

**Notes:**

1. `bzr push PATH --no-tree` to a PATH that's not exist , will create branch **WITH** tree.
2. Once branch is created without tree or remove-path was executed , you can
   use `push` with or without `` `--no-tree `` switch and the branch will stay without tree.

Answer (score 0):

The `--no-trees` is an option of the **repository** itself.

If you want the formal branch to have another structure, you must have it **outside the repository**.
Example:

```
proj_name (FOLDER)
    developer a (integrator) (REPO --no-trees)
        trunk      (branch)
        feature a  (branch)
        feature b  (branch)
    developer b (REPO --no-trees)
        trunk      (branch)
        feature a  (branch)
        feature b  (branch)
    formal version (REPO with tree!)
```

or you can have a repo at the developper level, and another at formal version.
THis way, you have a different op^tion for each repo.

Comment: I want tree on all branches and no tree in formal version . I think the directory structure I've suggested use the shared repository advantages better. Am i right? anyhow , I learned from Martin Pool that I can use 'bzr remove-tree PATH' and remove the tree of formal version.

Comment: remove-tree is indeed the best way to go about this. You can also avoid creating the tree altogether when you create a branch by specifying "bzr branch --no-tree".

Comment: @Gil.I Does that means that you have the solution ? If so, please publish it !

Comment: @TridentT , I posted the answer